# Is the number of concurrent connections particular to a specific data base?

Tags: mysql

Is the number of concurrent connections particular to a database or to the whole mysql database server?

Comment: Is the number of concurrent connections WHAT?

Comment: I made an edit that I think is what the OOP meant. @panja feel free to roll back if I got it wrong (but then please clarify what you mean.)

Comment: It's worth noting that don't really *connect* to a _database_: you connect to the _server_ and, afterwards, you can optionally issue a USE command to set the current database so it can be used to find objects when don't specify a fully qualified name.

Answer (score 0):

The number is whatever you want it to be. However, if you want to *limit* it, MySQL allows you do it at several levels:

- For the whole server: set the [max_connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections) global variable
- For each user: issue the [appropriate GRANT command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-resources.html)

See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/too-many-connections.html